# CmIs it possible to emulate a Logitech wireless (Unifying) mouse on an android?

Tags: emulation, mouse, termux, unify

I have a nano unifying reciever,but I've not got the mouse. Would it be posfible to emulate the mouse on android?

I've searched up solutions and only found that you can keyjack a unifying receiver using an arduino. Nothing on just android.